# MySQL - trocar conteúdo da coluna de charset ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, iso-8859-1

É possível trocar o charset de conteúdo de colunas específicas?

Possuo uma base de dados com a seguinte arquitetura:
:: IdConteudo (int autoincrement)
:: Titulo (vchar)
:: Resumo (vchar)
:: Conteudo (LongText)

No formulário quando cadastrou e/ou alterou os conteúdos, as colunas Titulo e Resumo estão com acentuação normal e a coluna Conteúdo, por ter vindo de um editor wysiwyg configurado em ISO-8859-1,está com a acentuação e caracteres especiais alterados para esse padrão de charset.

Dessa forma, queria ver se:

1. Preciso fazer alguma rotina no PHP que lista e atualiza via código para todos as colunas ficarem no charset ISO-8859-1 ou UTF-8;
   ou
2. Existe alguma rotina interna (Alter Table, etc) que executa esse ajuste pra mim.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna TEXT [...] CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: Vou testar e te retorno. Isso funcionaria ao contrário também de utf-8 para iso-8859-1?

Comment: Funciona sim @BrennoSacramento

Comment: Os dados existentes são convertidos?